# Handling Multiple WCF service calls

Tags: c#, wcf

i have a WCF service exposed to a TIBCO BW, which calls the service with mulitple xml messages 
at once, i need to modify my wcf service to handle multiple service calls as in multiple xml messages at once in parallel.

is there any attribute we need to add to the service, to make it multithreaded

pls help

Comment: Could this question/answer be your solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891635/setting-wcf-service-for-multiple-client-calls

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse there are.

I would start by reading this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and

I believe it contains the answers to all your questions.